# Userforms/Multipage- Disabling next button unless option buttons selected

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a multipage userform including entry details page and am using "NEXT" button to move onto next pages. ( There are 5 question pages + 1 entry detail page)
Here is the code that I am using to navigate.

```
If QuestionairePages.value < QuestionairePages.Pages.Count - 1 Then
    QuestionairePages.value = QuestionairePages.value + 1

End If
```

Is there a way to disable the moving to the next pages unless all options buttons selected on specific pages?

Comment: Sheet? I am moving to next page which includes other additional option buttons

Comment: You can just utilise another if-statement `IF Option1.Value = FALSE and Option2.Value = False Then MsgBox "Please complete the form" ELSE [the code in the question]` I am unaware of a better way to assign option groups for form validation

Comment: Are your OptionButtons grouped? With selected you mean "ticked"?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor The problem is my questions (option buttons) are starting at 3rd page, and message boxing popping up from first page to option buttons.

Comment: @EvR No, they aren't grouped.

Comment: Why not have the page change sub called following the validation for that page; If you are calling a sub from the next button, you hit validation just for that page then call the page change sub... Alternatively you can do a Select Case on the page number and do your validation for that page...

Comment: @mesakon If you're trying to prevent people from skipping around the userform, you should also consider removing the tabs (if you haven't already.) I don't remember exactly how that's done, but I believe it's a setting you can change in the developers tab on the multipage properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough information to write exactly what you need, but you can try with the `.visible` command and with the boolean on the option button like this :

```
If YourOptionButton1 = true then
 YourButtonNext.Visible = False
End if
```

Comment: There is also an `.Enabled` property, which would still leave the button visible, but un-clickable.

Comment: @Mistella .Enabled property exactly what I am lookig for but I could combine it with navigation code.